# JOIN com duas consultas na mesma tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso de dois resultados diferentes vindo na mesma tabela com JOIS

Funciona assim

Tenho a tabela PRODUCAO e a tabela BANCO

Na tabela produção, eu pego o ID do banco na tebela banco e me retorna o nome do banco, Porem tenho um segundo campo chamado BANCO_SALDO

Que pega na mesma tabela BANCO o ID do banco e me retorna o nome do banco.

Como eu consigo relacionar estas duas tabelas e me mostrando os nomes em cada campo que necessito?

```
SELECT * FROM producao 
JOIN promotora ON id_promotora = promotora_produ
JOIN banco ON id_banco = banco_produ
JOIN B AS banco ON id_banco = banco_port_produ
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer uma consulta fazendo direto com a tabela do banco. Como no exemplo:

```
SELECT PROD.ID, B1.NOME, B2.NOME, PROD.VALOR
FROM PRODUCAO PROD
INNER JOIN BANCO B1 ON PROD.IDBANCOCONTA = B1.ID  
INNER JOIN BANCO B2 ON PROD.IDBANCOSALDO = B2.ID
```

Fiz um exemplo rodando também: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44f9b2/1

Comment: Entendi, obrigado !