# Como realizar uma consulta SQL SERVER semelhante ao PROCV do Excel?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, procv

Tenho uma tabela de `valores` e uma tabela de `dicionário`. Para obter o valor referente utilizo a seguinte sentença:

```
SELECT DICIONARIO.KEY_TEXTO FROM VALORES
LEFT JOIN DICIONARIO ON VALORES.KEY1 = DICIONARIO.KEY_VALUE
```

Porém, minha tabela de valores tem várias colunas chaves conforme abaixo:

```
ID - KEY1 - KEY2 - KEY3
```

E a tabela valores:

```
KEY_VALUE - KEY_TEXTO
```

Como faço para obter o resultado semelhante ao `PROCV` das 3 chaves em uma única linha (distribuído em colunas)?

Para facilitar o entendimento, segue o modelo abaixo:

TABELA VALORES

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

TABELA DICIONÁRIO

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

RESULTADO ESPERADO

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja se ajuda     https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/308263/como-fazer-um-inner-join-em-uma-unica-tabela-com-3-chaves

Comment: Não consegui resolver por esse exemplo. Inclui mais informações na pergunta para facilitar a visualização do problema.

Comment: Pelo que entendi se precisa instanciar a mesma tabela mais de uma vez ... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263854/join-com-duas-consultas-na-mesma-tabela

Comment: Com esse exemplo consegui solucionar, obrigado!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consegui solucionar utilizando como base esse exemplo [JOIN com duas consultas na mesma tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263854/join-com-duas-consultas-na-mesma-tabela)

A solução ficou assim:

```
select valores.codcontrato, valores.codcadastro, valores.id, dict1.KEY_TEXT, dict2.KEY_TEXT from TABELAS_VALORES valores
left join TABELA_DICIONARIO dict1 on valores.KEY1 = dict1.KEY_VALUE
left join TABELA_DICIONARIO dict2 on valores.KEY12 = dict2.KEY_VALUE
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Resumindo, é preciso mostrar os resultados da coluna DICIONÁRIO.KEY_TEXTO três vezes, cada uma de acordo com as ordens como aparecem nas colunas VALORES.KEY1, VALORES.KEY2 e VALORES.KEY3.

É necessário aplicar conceitos de múltiplos JOIN e Self JOIN.

Primeiramente, faremos um JOIN simples:

```
SELECT valores.Id, valores.Key1, dicionário.Key_Value, dicionário.Key_Texto
FROM valores LEFT JOIN dicionário
ON valores.Key1 = dicionário.Key_Value
```

O LEFT JOIN mantém os registros da tabela à esquerda (a primeira em nossa ordem de leitura) imutável, então "encaixa" os registros da tabela à direita de forma compatível. Veja como o pedido `valores.Key1 = dicionário.Key_Value` é obedecido, então a coluna `dicionário.Key_Texto`, que é o que você deseja mostrar, obedece a essa organização. O resultado deve ser como segue:

[LEFT JOIN Ilustrativo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZKWm.png)

Agora, removeremos as colunas `valores.Key1` e `dicionário.Key_Value`, que foram incluídas na *query* para fins ilustrativos. Incluiremos, ainda, um *alias* para a tabela `dicionário` - isso será imprescindível para que a mesma coluna seja selecionada várias vezes em ordens diferentes.

```
SELECT valores.Id, dict1.Key_Texto
FROM valores LEFT JOIN dicionário dict1
ON valores.Key1 = dict1.Key_Value
```

As colunas `Key_Texto` e `Key_Value` pertencem à tabela `dict1`, que é um outro nome que demos à tabela `dicionário` através de `LEFT JOIN dicionário dict1`. O resultado deve ser como segue:

[LEFT JOIN simples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIKRJ.png)

Por fim, basta adicionar `Key_Texto` mais duas vezes. Porém, embora seja possível selecionar a mesma coluna várias vezes, terá um erro de ambiguidade se você fizer dois LEFT JOIN com a mesma coluna à direita - afinal, você quer juntar a `Key_Value` com a `Key1` ou com a `Key2`?

Para evitar a ambiguidade, daremos três *aliases* para a tabela `dicionário`.

```
SELECT valores.Id, dict1.Key_Texto, dict2.Key_Texto, dict3.Key_Texto
FROM valores

LEFT JOIN dicionário dict1
ON valores.Key1 = dict1.Key_Value

LEFT JOIN dicionário dict2
ON valores.Key2 = dict2.Key_Value

LEFT JOIN dicionário dict3
ON valores.Key3 = dict3.Key_Value
```

O resultado deve ser como segue:

[LEFT JOIN múltiplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIYmm.png)